# Create a custom `ls` but only for manual use

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, ls

I'm thinking of writing my own `ls` command. Mostly as a learning experience, but I also think I can make it a bit more useful (for me) than the default.

I'm worried though that if I alias `ls`, this also interferes with any bash/sh scripts that use ls as it's output.

Is there a way to override `ls`, but only when it's not used in scripts (or pipes?)

Comment: Why not name your version something other than `ls`?  Maybe `yals`?

Comment: Call it `yals` and then `alias ls=yals`. Interactive shell aliases don't affect scripts

Comment: Oh, that works? Then feel free to submit it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're worried that aliasing your version of `ls` will interfere with other processes.

Let's have a look at the POSIX standard.

From the [man page of `alias`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/alias.1p.html):

> Historical versions of the KornShell have allowed aliases to be
> exported to scripts that are invoked by the same shell. This is
> triggered by the alias −x flag; it is allowed by this volume of
> POSIX.1‐2008 only when an explicit extension such as −x is used. The
> standard developers considered that aliases were of use primarily to
> interactive users and **that they should normally not affect shell
> scripts** called by those users; functions are available to such
> scripts.

So, what does "normally" mean for bash? For instance, which version of `ls` would be used inside a shell script?

From the [man page of `bash`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is **not interactive**, unless the
> expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of
> shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

That means, you don't have to worry about *shell scripts* - they will use the unaliased version of `ls`.

But what about *pipes*? Again, we can combine those two man pages for great good:

From the man page of `bash`:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
> a subshell).

From the man page of `alias`:

> An alias definition shall affect the current shell execution
> environment and the execution environments of the subshells of the
> current shell. When used as specified by this volume of POSIX.1‐2008,
> the alias definition shall not affect the parent process of the
> current shell nor any utility environment invoked by the shell

That is, while your alias will not be used inside shell scripts, it will be used in pipes.